# application of ord() function in the control structures

Tags: php, syntax, ord

I'm having this piece of the code, where there is a string that can contain both alphabet characters or digits and i need to tell them apart. Wouldn't it be logic to use the function `ord()`? Sure it would!

```
    $r_1 = $_POST["r1"];

    $reag_1 = explode (" ", $r_1);

    foreach ($reag_1 as $k => $v) {

      if ( ord($v) != (48 || 49 || 50 || 51 || 52 || 53 || 54 || 55 || 56 || 57)){

      // if its a digit then do some stuff

      } else {

      // then its something else and lets do some OTHER stuff

      }
    }
```

Now the funny thing is that whatever I feed to an `$reag_1` seems to go only to `true` path. I double checked `var_dump()`-ed the `$reag_1` and traced where the program goes. There *are* alphabetic characters in that array. Where is my mistake that doesn't let the algorithm to go the proper way? I have a feeling I keep making a very basic syntax error.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `(ord($v)>=48) and (ord($v)<=57)`.

You can even use `>=Ord("0")` and `<=Ord("9")`.

There is even [`is_numeric`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) function.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried

 if ((ord($v) >= 48) and (ord($v) <= 57))

it helped, but im going to use is_numeric!

Comment: I corrected `chr` to `ord`, it would be useful for example `ord('A')` to `ord('Z')` if you want capital letters etc.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, this line is not logically correct in PHP:

```
if ( ord($reag_1[$k]) != (48 || 49 || 50 || 51 || 52 || 53 || 54 || 55 || 56 || 57))
```

You must use:

```
if(ord($reag_1[$k]) != 48 || ord($reag_1[$k]) != 49 ...)
```

or better way to use:

```
$array = array(48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57)
if(in_array(ord($reag_1[$k]), $array)){
```